# Batch File Running Slow When Creating Text File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I have a batch file that converts an Excel spreadsheet to a tab delimited text file, removes the first line of text (headers), and executes a SQL Server stored procedure that uses a BULK INSERT statement to import the text file into a table.

All the results when it runs are correct, but the portion removing the first line of text runs incredibly slow. With my test file of about 1500 lines, it takes about 35 seconds to create a 335 KB txt file.

```
cscript ExcelToTxt.vbs %dSourceFilePath% %dTemp%

for /f "skip=1 delims=*" %%a in (%dTemp%) do (
    echo %%a >>%dDestinationFilePath%
)
```

The script converts the Excel file to text file `%dTemp%`, then that file has it's first line skipped when creating the final file. Am I missing something that's slowing this down? Or is there a better way for me to accomplish this? Every other part part of this script runs as fast as I would expect it to.

Comment: Add the code to skip the first line to the vbscript and write directly to the destination file. If you really have the need for speed, don't use VB or batch scripts, write it in something that compiles to a native executable or go find one of the many programs that already accomplish exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why do you have `delims=*`?

Comment: If it is under 65,000 lines then using the `MORE` command to skip the first line will be much quicker.  But I would have thought your SQL procedure could be programmed to skip the header record.  My db people do that with all the files I send to them.  In your current code it would be much quicker if you did a single redirect as well. `(for /f "skip=1 delims=*" %%a in (%dTemp%) do echo %%a)>%dDestinationFilePath%`

Comment: My test file was small, but files could be over 65,000 lines. I recognize that there are better ways to do this, but I have minimal experience outside of databases, so this is pushing into new territory for me. I'm trying to minimize the manual steps that are currently taken daily to move data from a vendor's report into SQL Server. I'm open to other ideas and suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options for you to chose from.

1) Change your existing code so that it is not opening and closing a file handle for every line of the file you are outputting to the output file.

```
(for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in (%dTemp%) do echo %%a)>%dDestinationFilePath%
```

2) Use the `MORE` command if the input file is less than 65,000 lines.

```
more +1 %dTemp% >%dDestinationFilePath%
```

Comment: The first one works well for me for now. Thanks! Took a few seconds to run through 30,000 lines. For my own education, are the parenthesis making it complete the `for` loop before opening the file?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Powershell to skip the first line.

```
SET "dTemp=thefile.txt"
SET "dDestinationFilePath=zzz.txt"
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-Content %dTemp% |" ^
    "Select-Object -Skip 1 |" ^
    "Set-Content %dDestinationFilePath%"
```

The default `-ReadCount` for `Get-Content` is now 1. So, this should be good for reading large files as well.

Comment: For the files I've needed to convert to import into SQL Server, they've been as large as 100,000 lines. That's not to say they will never be larger though. In the long run, I'll look into a .Net script or something similar. I've got no experience there, and the batch file + vbscript seemed like the fastest path for me in the short term.

Comment: I changed the comment about large files. Please let me know if this works for you.